# Get URI from resource in ResultSet

Tags: java, rdf, sparql, jena, linkedmdb

I am trying to get the URI from the a resource in Java, but it is always `null`. Right now, I am trying this:

```java
for ( ; rs.hasNext() ; ) {
  QuerySolution qs  = rs.next();
  System.out.println( qs.getLiteral("label"));
  System.out.println( qs.getResource("label"));
  …
```

The literal is returned just fine, I even tried the resource "?film", but still resource is null.
Here is my SPARQL query:

```
PREFIX mdb: <http://data.linkedmdb.org/resource/movie/film>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 
select ?label ?film where {
  ?film mdb:id ?uri .
  ?film rdfs:label ?label . 
  filter regex(?label,  + queryVar +
}
```

`queryVar` is just the user input, for example "Batman".

Edit:I had an typo in my query: this was my query:

> String sparqlQuery =  "PREFIX mdb:
>   http://data.linkedmdb.org/resource/movie/film" + "PREFIX rdfs:
>   http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema# " + "select ?label ?film" +
>   "where " + "{ ?film mdb:id ?uri ." + "?film rdfs:label ?label . " + "
>   }" +  "";
>
> See closely at ?film and where, they become filmwhere, thats the
>   problem.

Thanks to Joshua I figured it out.

Comment: Now that you've found a solution, perhaps you can update the SPARQL query in the question to reflect what the _actual_ problem was (i.e., update the question to be `select ?label ?filmwhere { ... }` or `select ?label where { ... }`, so that we can create an answer that addresses it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation for `QuerySolution#getResource`](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/com/hp/hpl/jena/query/QuerySolution.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) says

> `Resource getResource(String varName)`
>
> Return the value of the named
>   variable in this binding, casting to a Resource. A return of null
>   indicates that the variable is not present in this solution. An
>   exception indicates it was present but not a resource.

If you're getting `null`, then some value isn't present in the query solution.  However, without seeing your *actual* query, it's impossible to tell whether you're getting empty results for some reason (e.g., the `queryVar` isn't what you think it is), or not.  If `queryVar` is just a String without surrounding quotes, you'd end up with a query like

```
filter regex(?label,Batman)
```

instead of

```
filter regex(?label,"Batman")
```

At any rate, I modified your query to be one that we can run with Jena's command line tools:

```
PREFIX mdb: <http://data.linkedmdb.org/resource/movie/film>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 
select ?label ?film
where {
  service <http://data.linkedmdb.org/sparql> {
    ?film mdb:id ?uri .
    ?film rdfs:label ?label . 
    filter regex(?label, "Batman")
  }
}
```

When I run this, I get results like:

```
$ arq --query query.sparql --data data.n3 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| label                                | film                                           |
=========================================================================================
| "Batman"                             | <http://data.linkedmdb.org/resource/film/2>    |
| "Batman"                             | <http://data.linkedmdb.org/resource/film/3>    |
| "Batman & Robin"                     | <http://data.linkedmdb.org/resource/film/4>    |
| "Batman: Mask of the Phantasm"       | <http://data.linkedmdb.org/resource/film/737>  |
| "Batman: Mystery of the Batwoman"    | <http://data.linkedmdb.org/resource/film/974>  |
| "Batman Beyond: Return of the Joker" | <http://data.linkedmdb.org/resource/film/1802> |
| "Batman & Mr. Freeze: SubZero"       | <http://data.linkedmdb.org/resource/film/2124> |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

in which `label` and `film` are always bound. All of the labels are literals, so you should be able to do

```java
qs.getLiteral("label")
```

and get a literal.  It sounds more like you want the URI of the `film` variable, which you would do with

```java
qs.getResource("film").getURI()
```

You could, of course, use `toString()` afterward if you want the URI string.

As an aside, rather than doing

```java
"filter(?label, " + queryVar + "…"
```

you might want to consider using a [ParameterizedSparqlString](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/com/hp/hpl/jena/query/ParameterizedSparqlString.html) to safely substitute the queryVar in.  Otherwise, what happens with `queryVar` is something like

```java
"\"Batman\") UNION { ?film hasPassword ?label }"
```

and it gets substituted in?  You suddenly leak a bunch of information.  Even if nothing sensitive gets out, you could still end up causing a big load on the SPARQL endpoint, effectively launching a denial-of-service attack.

Comment: If I use Label I get the following error  com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.LiteralImpl cannot be cast to com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Resource

By the way, isnt it getURI?

Comment: You're right; it should be getURI, and I've updated my answer.  The exception is expected, as per the javadoc for getResource: "An exception indicates it was present but not a resource."  A Literal _is not_ a Resource.  A Resource _is not_ a Literal.  You can do `qs.getResource("film")` and get a resource, since those values are resources, and you can do `qs.getLiteral("label")` and get a literal, since those values are literals.

Comment: I did have a typo in my code, too.  I meant `qs.getResource("film").getURI()`, not `qs.getResource("label").getURI()`.  Sorry.  I did say though, that "you want the URI of the film variable, which you would do with", which should have suggested that `"label"` was a copy/paste typo for `"film"`.

Comment: @user2715404 The [pastebin code](http://pastebin.com/L7Qs3Q1A) is very different from the code in the question.   It only selects `label` (it has `select ?label where`, with no `?film`), so, just as the documentation says, you get "null [which] indicates that the variable is not present in this solution."

Comment: Okay, I have now changed to your query, but still I get the null pointer.. Could you perhaps see my code? Sorry, its messy:
http://pastebin.com/eYnecZ54

Comment: Ye sorry about that first pastebin, fixed to ?label ?film, and it worked great ! Now I only need to find whats wrong in my code..

Comment: I don't see any SPARQL query in that latest pastebin, http://pastebin.com/eYnecZ54, just `sparqlQuery = m.getSarqlQuery(searchText);`.

Comment: The sparql query is identical to yours : 

   String sparqlQuery = 
    "PREFIX mdb: <http://data.linkedmdb.org/resource/movie/film>" +
       "PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> " +
       "select ?label ?film" +
    "where " +
    "{ ?film mdb:id ?uri ." +
    "?film rdfs:label ?label . " +
   
    " }" + 
    "";

Comment: m is just a class where I have stored the query

Comment: It'd be much more helpful to see that in pastebin than in the comments.  E.g., something like `"select ?label ?film" + "where "+` looks like you'll end up with `select ?label ?filmwhere {` with a variable named `filmwhere` which won't be helpful.   (It's still legal though, since the `where` is optional, and `select ... where { ... }` is equivalent to `select ... { ... }`.  This is also a good reason for putting newlines in your SPARQL queries with `\n`.  Also a good reason for printing your SPARQL queries and putting them in the question so that we can _exactly_ what your query is. :)

Comment: How embarrassing,  you are in fact right.  I am sorry,  spent so many hours in front of the code that I obviously went blind..